# What happens to the X-ray diffraction (XRD) pattern if we use laser as a incident beam?

Tags: laser, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

In X-ray diffraction (XRD) pattern we use X-ray because it has the wavelength of the same order as that of the inter-planar separation. Now if instead of X-rays I use laser light, then how it will affect the XRD pattern?

Comment: Assuming you mean a *visible light* laser, there will be no diffraction.   The spacing between scatterers is less than a wavelength so there is no diffraction.  (Alternatively, you can say that there is only zero-order diffraction.)

Comment: Just here to point out that above comment is right in almost all cases. The case in which there will be some measurable XRD-like diffraction for visible light is synthetic opals. Silica balls which form those opals are of same order of size as a visible light wavelength, so the gist of argument holds.